# angular reactive form throws "Cannot find control with name" for irrelevant model field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I'm attempting to build an edit component with Angular Reactive forms. However, I get the error "Error: Cannot find form control with name: created.", with "created" being a property on my model.

However, created is not an editable field and should not be bound to the form. I don't specify it in my form builder nor is there a control on my edit.html page. It is only present on my model. How do I tell form validator to ignore this and other irrelevant model properties?

Here's my model:

```
        export class User {
      id: number;
      userName: string;
      password: string;
      passwordHash: string;
      lastName: string;
      firstName: string;
      email: string;
      created: string;
      lastLogin: string;
      description: string;
      isSaved: boolean;
      passsword:string;
      passwordConfirm:string;
    }
```

Here's my component:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { first } from "rxjs/operators";
import { User } from "../../model/user.model";
import { UserService } from "../../service/user.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-user',
  templateUrl: './edit-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-user.component.css']
})
export class EditUserComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User;
  editForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let userId = window.localStorage.getItem("editUserId");
    if (!userId) {
      alert("Invalid action.")
      this.router.navigate(['list-user']);
      return;
    }
    this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [''],
      userName: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      passwordConfirm: ['', Validators.required],
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.email],
      description: [''],
    });
    this.userService.getUserById(+userId)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.editForm.setValue(data);
      });
  }

  onSubmit() {

    if(!this.editForm.value.passwordConfirm){
      console.log("password confirmed is undefined. Setting");
      this.editForm.value.passwordConfirm = this.editForm.value.password;
    }

    this.userService.updateUser(this.editForm.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          alert('User updated successfully.');
          this.router.navigate(['list-user']);
        },
        error => {
          alert("En error occured and changes should not be saved. Details: " + error);
        });
  }
}
```

Here's my html:

```
        <div class="col-md-6 user-container">
          <h2 class="text-center">Edit User</h2>
          <form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

            <div class="hidden" style="display:none;">
              <input type="text" formControlName="id" placeholder="id" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">
            </div>

            <!-- todo: replace display none with bootstrap class -->

            <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
              <input type="text" formControlName="userName" placeholder="userName" name="userName" class="form-control"
                id="userName" readonly="true">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
              <input formControlName="firstName" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
              <input formControlName="lastName" placeholder="Last name" name="lastName" class="form-control" id="lastName">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input formControlName="email" placeholder="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="description">Description:</label>
              <input formControlName="description" placeholder="Description" name="description" class="form-control"
                id="description">
            </div>

            <hr>

            <h5>Change password</h5>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">New password:</label>
              <input type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="password" name="password" class="form-control"
                id="password">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="passwordConfirm">Confirm password:</label>
              <input type="password" formControlName="passwordConfirm" placeholder="passwordConfirm" name="passwordConfirm"
                class="form-control" id="passwordConfirm">
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
          </form>
        </div>
```

Here's the error details:

**Error: Cannot find form control with name: created.
core.js:5847**
message:"Cannot find form control with name: created."
stack:"Error: Cannot find form control with name: created.\n    at FormGroup._throwIfControlMissing (https://localhost:5001/vendor.js:70056:19)\n    at https://localhost:5001/vendor.js:69913:19\n    at Array.forEach ()\n    at FormGroup.setValue (https://localhost:5001/vendor.js:69912:28)\n    at SafeSubscriber._next (https://localhost:5001/main.js:1937:28)\n    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (https://localhost:5001/vendor.js:95425:16)\n    at SafeSubscriber.next (https://localhost:5001/vendor.js:95363:22)\n    at Subscriber._next (https://localhost:5001/vendor.js:95309:26)\n    at Subscriber.next (https://localhost:5001/vendor.js:95286:18)\n    at MapSubscriber._next (https://localhost:5001/vendor.js:100330:26)"

Comment: Probably `created` getting added in `editForm` through this line of code - `this.editForm.setValue(data);`. Can you please `console.log` and check ?

Comment: Yes, "data" contains an entire user model object from my API: Object {firstName: "FirstName", lastName: "LastName", password: null, created: "2020-01-21T10:48:47.4345182+01:00", lastLogin: "2020-01-20T15:31:30.277", …} etc...

Comment: So, keep the `editForm` and `formModel` separate. Populate `editForm` from `formModel`. `editForm` would contain only the fields that are required on the form. `formModel` would contain all the fields and would match the schema as returned by API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like that you want to set a `User` object into the form, which doesn't have a control called `created`.

You either remove that field from the object that you pass to `setValue`, or instead of `setValue` use `patchValue`, which seems to ignore unknown fields, and also, only touches those controls, which are specified in the object passed in and leaves the other controls alone, as opposed to `setValue`, which reset those controls, which are not specified in the object passed in.

Comment: Thanks! patchValue() did the trick. I should add that I think that's an odd behavior for setValue(), to demand all fields in the model must be in the form. How often do you have a model that exactly corresponds to your form? You'd have to have one unique model for every form.

Comment: I somewhat agree with that, but also agree with the form API forcing you to explicitly handle the conversion from the model to the form. Sometimes, for more complex form, I even create an interface for the form value, write separate converters (you probably need one for the other way too, when you extract the data from the form to pass it to the backend) and tests for those.

Answer (score 2):

Angular reactive forms accepts only those values which are present in form builder, if you have some extra properties in the object, you are using to set values, it gives error for that property. Here, you have `created` as extra, if you solved somehow that error, it will again give error to `lastLogin`as it is not part of form builder.

```
this.userService.getUserById(+userId)
  .subscribe(data => {
   const propertyToSelect = ['id','userName', 'password','passwordConfirm', 'firstName', 'lastName','email', 'description']
   const objectToSetValue = propertyToSelect.map((property) => {property: data[property]})
   this.editForm.setValue(objectToSetValue);
  });
```